# why is sails-auth logout returning a 404

Tags: express, sails.js, passport.js

I am running a sails application locally and I can authenticate and everything ok, but when I try to logout I get a 404 not found.

[image: 404 not found screenshot]

Which is odd because in node_modules/sails-auth/config/routes.js there is a line for it

```
module.exports.routes = {
  'post /register': 'UserController.create',
  'get /logout': 'AuthController.logout',  // THIS ONE HERE

  'post /auth/local': 'AuthController.callback',
  'post /auth/local/:action': 'AuthController.callback',

  'get /auth/:provider': 'AuthController.provider',
  'get /auth/:provider/callback': 'AuthController.callback',
  'get /auth/:provider/:action': 'AuthController.callback'
};
```

the /auth/local and /register endpoints work as expected, just not the logout link.

I verified in node_modules/sails-auth/api/controllers/AuthController.js

```
  logout: function (req, res) {
    req.logout();
    delete req.user;
    delete req.session.passport;
    req.session.authenticated = false;

    if (!req.isSocket) {
      res.redirect(req.query.next || '/');
    }
    else {
      res.ok();
    }
  },
```

Comment: Try running using `DEBUG=express:* node app.js` for verbose logs.

Comment: @Sangharsh here is what it gave me
`dispatching GET /logout (/logout) +10s                     
matched get /* +0ms                                        
matched get /* +1ms                                        
matched get /logout +0ms                                   
matched get /logout +107ms                                 
dispatching GET / (/) +28ms                                
matched get /* +0ms                                        
matched get /* +1ms                                        
matched get /* +0ms`